# Rendering route inside child view

Tags: ember.js, separation-of-concerns

I've been trying to clean up some of my code, and wanted to refactor a 'sidebar' partial into a View/Template combo, since there are navigation elements that need to be controlled by the child views that get rendered in the outlet.

It currently looks like this

```
Map (Route/View/Template)
  Sidebar (partial) - has {{outlet}}

Other routes render in Sidebar {{outlet}}
```

Now I want to make the Sidebar have a View, not just be a template, since I want to control some UI changes based on what's rendered within there.

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/825/edit) with an example that doesn't work. I also tried `{{render 'sidebar'}}` but that didn't work either. Using RC.8 by the way.

*Edit*
Another attempt [here](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/844/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sidebar template should be rendered in the application template (not the index one) otherwise when you enter the /test route it doesn't show up.

Then in renderTemplate of App.TestRoute you can render the templates in the 2 outlets (sidebar and main).

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render('test');
    this.render('test_sidebar',{
      into: 'sidebar',
      outlet: 'sidebar'
    });
  }
});
```

See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/847/edit) example.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I think I got it, is it because only `index` or `test` can be active at a time, since both are sibling routes?

Comment: Exactly. To understand hierarchy and order with which templates are rendered i find useful [ember-extension](https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension).

Comment: For some reason I assumed that if you change where the template renders, then it changes that whole limitation.. :)